# Update Schema via an Eloquent Model, Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i'd like to know if it's possible at all to update the table schema in a Migration through a specific Eloquent Model, or if i actually need to pass in the name of the Table and Connection every single time.

I ask this because in my case this requires an additional configuration file that my package must publish to the end users, apart from the already required table Eloquent model (which is used for other purposes)

Answer (score 0):

You can update schema later and add or drop columns and/or index.

To do this you create a new migration and add the changes there. It will change the table over your previous version.

More info in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#modifying-columns).

For renaming the table

```
Schema::rename($from, $to);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables